# How to take . NET web app and point to different Oracle Databases?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I created a test web application and in this application I set up a connection to an Oracle DB (11g).  I am also using EF6 to pull data.

My question is how would I go about deploying this test web app to point at different databases (ie. DEV/QA/PROD)?

To further clarify all the information that I have is:

- Username
- Password
- Hostname
- SID

I do not have a Service name to work with.

So based on that information I was able to setup my connection:
[image]

So this means that my web app is now tied to a TNSNAMES.ora file that is currently pointing to a particular path on my machine.

So in this instance I have no idea how I would deploy to a QA/PROD server.  I see nothing in the web.config that shows me the location of the TNSNAMES.ora file.  So how would it know where to look?

Could there possibly be an easier way to connect and deploy if I was given a service name to work with?

EDIT:
This is the other option to connect, however this looks dependent on a service name which I do not have.
[image]

Comment: Why not you see your connectionstring in web.config file?

Comment: The web.config has DATA SOURCE=OracleTNS  with my username/password creds.  It does not list the DB or SID in the web.config.  It's going out to the tnsnames.ora file to get that information.

Comment: i'm not sure if you can use tns-less connection strings with EF.  but pre-EF (ado.net), the world was much easier using tns-less connection strings.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/tns-less-connection-string/

Comment: I don't think so.  I believe the only way is the TNS or EZ Connect, and I believe the EX Connect will only work with a service name which I don't have.